# Error with makefile, building from all in src directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I have been attempting to replicate a makefile I found online. I am currently stuck at the following error:

```
MyComputer:folderName userName$ make
make: bin/kernel: No such file or directory
make: *** [bin/kernel] Error 1
```

The makefile source is as follows:

```
### Typing 'make' will create the executable file.
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = 
LIBS = -lstdc++

TARGET = kernel
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin
#TARGETDIR = $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cc)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cc=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cc
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

#$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $@

#make clean removed from this code, unnecessary
```

Things I have tried:

- Changing `$(BINDER)/$(TARGET):` to `$(BINDER)` (`make: bin: No such file or directory`)
- Changing folder permissions and running as sudo (no effect)
- Making the bin/kernel folder (Permission Denied w/ sudo and chmod 777)
- Praying to our dark lord Cthulhu (possible inevitable doom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Makefile assumes the project directory is structured in the following way:

```
.
├── bin
├── Makefile
├── obj
└── src
    └── main.cc
```

I modified the linking phase as you did not have `$(LINKER)` defined:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = 
LIBS = -lstdc++

TARGET = kernel
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cc)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cc=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CC) -o $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cc
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
```

running `make` will now create the kernel binary.

```
.
├── bin
│   └── kernel
├── Makefile
├── obj
│   └── main.o
└── src
    └── main.cc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked. Small note to any future readers: I also messed up (this man's solution) line 17: `LFLAGS` should be `LDFLAGS`